# Install mongodb 3.4.22 community version on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

I need to install MongoDB 3.4.22 community version on ubuntu 18.04. I tired as described in the following link

[How to install a specific version of MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823676/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-mongodb)

But it gives the following errors

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-server
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-shell
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-mongos
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-tools
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the version that you specifically looking for is not present in the distro for Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)

You can check available versions [from here](http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mongodb-org/)